# Routing custom remote validation if an AdditionalFields parameter has been added

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a working `Custom Remote Validation` that is meant to check even if the user disables Javascript. Here is the code:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
        // Get the controller using reflection
        Type controller = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .FirstOrDefault(type => type.Name.ToLower() == string.Format("{0}Controller", 
                this.RouteData["controller"].ToString()).ToLower());
        if (controller != null)
        {
            // Get the action method that has validation logic
            MethodInfo action = controller.GetMethods()
                .FirstOrDefault(method => method.Name.ToLower() == 
                    this.RouteData["action"].ToString().ToLower());
            if (action != null)
            {
                // Create an instance of the controller class
                object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(controller);
                // Invoke the action method that has validation logic
                object response = action.Invoke(instance, new object[] { value });
                if (response is JsonResult)
                {
                    object jsonData = ((JsonResult)response).Data;
                    if (jsonData is bool)
                    {
                        return (bool)jsonData ? ValidationResult.Success : 
                            new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

      //  return ValidationResult.Success;
      return new ValidationResult(base.ErrorMessageString);
}
```

This is the action that I invoke will return a `JSON` which is a `bool`:

```
    public JsonResult IsEmailTaken(string email,string fname)
    {
        EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext();
        int x = emp.students.Where(row => row.email == email).ToList().Count();
        if (x >0 || fname != "Carl")
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

What is does is, it will check if the `Email` is already taken. I am testing `AddtionalFields` so what i want to happen is that, the form will be invalidated if the user's name isn't `Carl` so i added an extra parameter named `fname` (both of the parameters are the same as they are on the model).

And this is how I put my attribute:

```
 [RemoteEmailCheck("IsEmailTaken","Enrollment",ErrorMessage="Email is already in use. Please pick something else", AdditionalFields="fname")]
  public string email { get; set; }
```

My code works if it has no `AdditionalFields`, but if I add them, I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

and it's on this line:

```
object response = action.Invoke(instance, new object[] { value });
```

How do I change that to accommodate `AdditionalFields` ?

**Edit:** these are my constructors:

```
    public RemoteEmailCheckAttribute(string routeName) : base(routeName)
    {
    }

    public  RemoteEmailCheckAttribute(string action, string controller)
        : base(action, controller)
    {
    }

    public RemoteEmailCheckAttribute(string action, string controller, 
        string areaName) : base(action, controller, areaName)
    {
    }
```

Comment: You need to show the signature and constructor of your method. Are you inheriting from `RemoteAttribute`? - in which case `this.AdditionalFields` will contain the property names of the additional fields

Comment: You are inheriting `RemoteAttribute` so in the `IsValid()` method you can access the property names of the additional fields using `this.AdditionalFields`, split them to an array and then get the associated values from the ValidationContext (using `.GetProperty()` and `.GetValue()` - refer [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)) then add the values to the route

Comment: I am also confused about this line of code `object response = action.Invoke(instance, new object[] { value, });`. how do i insert them here to make them properly routed? do i need so specify `fname =??` ?

Comment: It needs to be `new object[] { value, the ValueOfTheFnameProperty }` - i.e. you need to pass the values to the method that match the order and type of the parameters in the method.

Comment: However I really think you over complicating this. Typically you have a `private bool IsEmailValid(string email,string fname)` method in your controller (or as a separate service) that does the database call and validation. And the `public JsonResult IsEmailTaken(string email,string fname)` method which calls `IsEmailValid()` and return the result as Json. Then in the POST method, also call the `IsEmailValid()` method. You current attribute is likely to fail if your using DI.